# When/Where is Flutter's main() method called from the Android and iOS side of things?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

If I understand correctly:
When we run an Android app built with Flutter, it first goes to the `AndroidManfiest.xml` file, looks for the `LAUNCHER` activity and launches it. This activity is `MainActivity.kt` by default that extends `FlutterActivity`.

But the Flutter part of the app begins when the `main()` method in `main.dart` gets called.

My question is, who calls this `main()` method?

For Android, is it the `MainActivity` that extends `FlutterActivity`? Or is there some logic in the `FlutterActivity` itself? Or is there some other mechanism altogether and I'm completely missing the point?

The same question applies to iOS too with `FlutterViewController` instead of `FlutterActivity`.

A link to the source code for this that just clarifies when does `main()` get called would be great.

Comment: The Dart runtime (or VM in debug builds) executes `main`.  The Dart runtime/VM is started by the Flutter engine.

Comment: Okay. Can you point me to the code that triggers the Dart VM in debug builds? 
When I run the iOS app from xcode, there has to be some configuration in some iOS specific file that does things differently than it would for a Swift/Obj-C iOS app i.e. triggering this Dart VM.

Comment: I don't remember the exact details, but I think you would have to look at the C++ and Objective-C code in [flutter_engine](https://github.com/flutter/engine), e.g. [`FlutterDartProject.mm`](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/shell/platform/darwin/ios/framework/Source/FlutterDartProject.mm).

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was curious about. Thanks! 

Documenting the direct links here for further reading:

iOS: https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/138c91c614d742c52aa5432b4cb921f0ff9fdee2/shell/platform/darwin/ios/framework/Headers/FlutterEngine.h#L22

Android: https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/f9d717cef57c3527750b5dfd293f8ca70d95d64e/shell/platform/android/io/flutter/embedding/android/FlutterActivity.java#L222

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## On iOS

A `main.m` file was autogenerated in your Flutter projects `ios/Runner` directory, which defines the regular, main function which a [C program implements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2108208/7365866), `int main(int argc, char* argv[]);`.

One compiled output can only have one main method, which the compiler will run immediately when the program is started. The following code creates a [`UIApplicationMain`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1622933-uiapplicationmain), which "Creates the application object and the application delegate and sets up the event cycle":

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

It's [simpler in **Swift**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388064/how-does-appdelegate-swift-replace-appdelegate-h-and-appdelegate-m-in-xcode-6-3), just annotate `AppDelegate` with `@UIApplicationMain`.

The AppDelegate is the class which launches Flutter, because it extends `FlutterAppDelegate`. When `FlutterAppDelegate` is instantiated, iOS will create the `FlutterViewController`, which creates a FlutterEngine. It creates `FlutterViewController` because the `FlutterViewController` is configured in the `Main.storyboard`, which has been specified in the applications `Info.plist`. So technically, Flutter apps are **Storyboard** apps .

[image: Screenshot of Xcode's Interface Builder with Main.storyboard open, with the identity inspector open showing the FlutterViewController as custom class.]

Anyway, when the storyboard is created by iOS, the `window` property is set on the AppDelegate. You can get the `FlutterViewController` in the AppDelegate using `window.rootViewController`. An Objective-C++ file, `FlutterViewController.mm`'s `sharedSetupWithProject` method creates a `FlutterEngine` using `[[FlutterEngine alloc]initWithName:...`:

```objectivec
- (void)sharedSetupWithProject:(nullable FlutterDartProject*)project
                  initialRoute:(nullable NSString*)initialRoute {
  // Need the project to get settings for the view. Initializing it here means
  // the Engine class won't initialize it later.
  if (!project) {
    project = [[[FlutterDartProject alloc] init] autorelease];
  }
  FlutterView.forceSoftwareRendering = project.settings.enable_software_rendering;
  auto engine = fml::scoped_nsobject<FlutterEngine>{[[FlutterEngine alloc]
                initWithName:@"io.flutter"
                     project:project
      allowHeadlessExecution:self.engineAllowHeadlessExecution
          restorationEnabled:[self restorationIdentifier] != nil]};

  if (!engine) {
    return;
  }

  _viewOpaque = YES;
  _weakFactory = std::make_unique<fml::WeakPtrFactory<FlutterViewController>>(self);
  _engine = std::move(engine);
  _flutterView.reset([[FlutterView alloc] initWithDelegate:_engine opaque:self.isViewOpaque]);
  [_engine.get() createShell:nil libraryURI:nil initialRoute:initialRoute];
  _engineNeedsLaunch = YES;
  _ongoingTouches.reset([[NSMutableSet alloc] init]);
  [self loadDefaultSplashScreenView];
  [self performCommonViewControllerInitialization];
}
```

Eventually, in `FlutterEngine.mm`, `launchEngine` is called, with the entrypoint (your **dart's main function**.)

```objectivec
- (void)launchEngine:(NSString*)entrypoint libraryURI:(NSString*)libraryOrNil {
  // Launch the Dart application with the inferred run configuration.
  self.shell.RunEngine([_dartProject.get() runConfigurationForEntrypoint:entrypoint
                                                            libraryOrNil:libraryOrNil]);
}
```

`Shell::RunEngine` is a C++ function implemented [in shell.cc](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/shell/common/shell.cc). I'm going to stop there for now. This is probably where the event loop starts , using `platform_runner->PostTask(...)`.

---

## On Android

In a generated Flutter project's android directory,  `MainActivity` is declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml` to be the application which launches from the home screen.

When the activity is launched, Android will call the activity's `onCreate` method. Because `MainActivity` extends `FlutterActivity`, this `onCreate` method is called. `FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate` is instantiated, and its `onAttach` method is called. Eventually, a Java representation of `FlutterEngine` is created using:

```java
    flutterEngine =
        new FlutterEngine(
            host.getContext(),
            host.getFlutterShellArgs().toArray(),
            /*automaticallyRegisterPlugins=*/ false,
            /*willProvideRestorationData=*/ host.shouldRestoreAndSaveState());
```

This communicates with the C++ FlutterEngine library using `FlutterJNI`.

> ```java
> /**
>  * Interface between Flutter embedding's Java code and Flutter engine's C/C++ code.
>  *
>  * <p>Flutter's engine is built with C/C++. The Android Flutter embedding is responsible for
>  * coordinating Android OS events and app user interactions with the C/C++ engine. Such coordination
>  * requires messaging from an Android app in Java code to the C/C++ engine code. This communication
>  * requires a JNI (Java Native Interface) API to cross the Java/native boundary.
>  *
> ```

Later, in `FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate`, `doInitialFlutterViewRun` is called, which creates a `DartEntryPoint`, **your main method again**, based on the FlutterActivity's `ActivityInfo`. This gets the entrpoint function name using the following, but it will default to `"main"`:

```
  @NonNull
  public String getDartEntrypointFunctionName() {
    try {
      Bundle metaData = getMetaData();
      String desiredDartEntrypoint =
          metaData != null ? metaData.getString(DART_ENTRYPOINT_META_DATA_KEY) : null;
      return desiredDartEntrypoint != null ? desiredDartEntrypoint : DEFAULT_DART_ENTRYPOINT;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
      return DEFAULT_DART_ENTRYPOINT;
    }
  }
```

Then, `flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().executeDartEntrypoint(entrypoint);` is called. So your main method has "been called". But this uses the `FlutterJNI` and the FlutterEngine C++ code. First, `flutterJNI.runBundleAndSnapshotFromLibrary` is called, and finally this **JNI** native method:

```
  private native void nativeRunBundleAndSnapshotFromLibrary(
      long nativeShellHolderId,
      @NonNull String bundlePath,
      @Nullable String entrypointFunctionName,
      @Nullable String pathToEntrypointFunction,
      @NonNull AssetManager manager);
```

This native method is defined in `platform_view_adroid_jni_impl.cc`:

```cpp
      {
          .name = "nativeRunBundleAndSnapshotFromLibrary",
          .signature = "(JLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;"
                       "Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;)V",
          .fnPtr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&RunBundleAndSnapshotFromLibrary),
      },
```

Where `RunBundleAndSnapshotFromLibrary` is a C++ method:

```cpp
static void RunBundleAndSnapshotFromLibrary(JNIEnv* env,
                                            jobject jcaller,
                                            jlong shell_holder,
                                            jstring jBundlePath,
                                            jstring jEntrypoint,
                                            jstring jLibraryUrl,
                                            jobject jAssetManager) {
  auto asset_manager = std::make_shared<flutter::AssetManager>();

  asset_manager->PushBack(std::make_unique<flutter::APKAssetProvider>(
      env,                                             // jni environment
      jAssetManager,                                   // asset manager
      fml::jni::JavaStringToString(env, jBundlePath))  // apk asset dir
  );

  auto entrypoint = fml::jni::JavaStringToString(env, jEntrypoint);
  auto libraryUrl = fml::jni::JavaStringToString(env, jLibraryUrl);

  ANDROID_SHELL_HOLDER->Launch(asset_manager, entrypoint, libraryUrl);
}
```

Where `AndroidShellHolder::Launch` is:

```cpp
void AndroidShellHolder::Launch(std::shared_ptr<AssetManager> asset_manager,
                                const std::string& entrypoint,
                                const std::string& libraryUrl) {
  if (!IsValid()) {
    return;
  }

  asset_manager_ = asset_manager;
  auto config = BuildRunConfiguration(asset_manager, entrypoint, libraryUrl);
  if (!config) {
    return;
  }
  shell_->RunEngine(std::move(config.value()));
}
```

Just like iOS, `Shell::RunEngine` is called.